# How should the option 'switchbuf' work?

Tags: vimrc, buffers, split

I recently discovered the option [`switchbuf`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27switchbuf%27) and tried to use it but I can't say if I don't understand how it should work or if it actually doesn't work on my Vim.

About the different possible values, the doc says:

> *useopen* If included, jump to the first open window that 
>                 contains the specified buffer (if there is one).
>   *usetab*  Like "useopen", but also consider windows in other tab  pages.

I have then used `set switchbuf=useopen,usetab` and the following commands in a new vim instance:

- Open a first buffer `:e file1`
- Split the screen `:split`
- Open a second buffer `:e file2`
- Go back to the first buffer `:e file1` (I have also used `:bN`)

The last commands to go to the first buffer open it in the second split. From what I understand from the doc the commands should place the cursor to the first split where the buffer is already open thanks to `useopen`. Also the behavior is the same when I try the same commands with tabs instead of splits.

- Is this behavior the expected one?
- If so could you explain what this option should do?
- If not I know that I'll have to debug my `.vimrc` but maybe is there a common setting known to interfere with `switchbuf`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`'switchbuf'` is only honored by quickfix commands (like `:cc`) and buffer-splitting commands (like `:sb`).

It doesn't affect `:buffer` and other "regular" buffer-related commands.

Comment: Oh I see. As the doc says first `This option controls the behavior when switching between buffers.` and only several lines later mentions quickfix commands and `sb` I thought that it was in addition of the regular buffer commands. Thanks!